# Virtual-work problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I have a very specific doubt about the next exercise:

I have the crane of the picture:

[image]

With a force $F_a=-K\varphi$ Applied on the point B, perpendicular witch AB, and another force $F_b=-K\psi$ Applied on the point C.
They ask me to find an equilibrium configuration with the virtual-job theorem.

I define a new basis wich moves with the first arm of the crane (AB):

$i'=i \sin(\varphi) + j \cos(\varphi)$

$j'=j \sin(\varphi)- i \cos(\varphi)$

And another base which moves with the second crane, as a function of the $"'"$ base

$i''=i' \sin(\varphi) + j' \cos(\varphi)$

$j''=j' \sin(\varphi)- i' \cos(\varphi)$

Also, I define the vector $r_1$, which goes from A to B. To find the virtual displacement, I must do: $\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial \varphi}$. BUT (and this is my question), the arm AB hasn't any relation with the movement of the BC arm. Then, in order to find the virtual dispement I must find $\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial \psi}$ which should be zero. **But**, I can write the vector $r_1$ as a function of the double $ '$basis, then derive it, and have something different from zero.

So ¿$\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial \psi}=0$?

Comment: While I don't believe this question is too esoteric and I think the answer may be useful for many people, I must vote to close the question because this is specifically an issue more related to introductory robotics (about which, a number of textbooks exist that could easily help you with this problem) and has little to do with physics specifically.

Comment: Excuse me, but I think this problem is absolutely about physics. In my course of "analitical mechanics" is the first topic given, and I would be realy grateful if someone can help me with it.
Moreover, the virtual-work theorem can be used to deduce the  Lagrangian Mechanics, and I really dont know anything about robotics.
Could you please remove the "off topic" thing of this question? I can rewrite the whole question in a few words, but I think that without the context, its going to be extremely difficult to answer properly